# Unable to view any data in Hive external table which is stored as ORC in HDFS containing hindi characters

Tags: csv, hive, hdfs

I am reading CSV from s3 using python pandas and converting it to spark dataframe to write in HDFS as ORC format. I could find data loaded in HDFS and getting the count of rows correctly, but unable to view the data for all columns in the hive external table mapped to HDFS location. Data contains English or Hindi words in a column. Please suggest.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. How are you trying to read that data, from spark or from hdfs shell command line? Could you please show some code what your are trying to do of? Please, provide some better explanation.

Comment: @Chema Reading CSV present in S3 bucket using pandas dataframe. Converting pandas dataframe to spark dataframe and writing in hdfs as ORC. while retrieving data from hive table could not view any data. But when I save it as text file I could view both Hindi and English words.
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), encoding='utf8')
df = df.astype(str)
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
df.write.mode('append').format('orc').save(path)
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}({}) stored as orc location '{}'""".format(table_name, str_columns, path)

Comment: Additional information, when I am storing the data in my local as ORC I could view the data through the hive, but when I do the same in the hive I could not view data. In EMR only when I save the data in CSV format I could view the data through the hive.